# Reversing order of integration for a triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{\sqrt{x}}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-y} 2y dzdydx$$

And I am asked to rearrange the order to integrate $y$ first then $z$. My changed terminals then become:

$$1\leq y\leq 1-z$$ and

$$1-\sqrt{x} \leq z \leq 0$$

However when I evaluate the integral the answer is not the same. Not sure where the mistake in my terminals are.

Comment: Wrote it wrong, see above for edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=\sqrt{x}}^1 \int_{z=0}^{1-y} 2y \, dz \, dy \, dx$$ is the original integral.  If the order of integration is to be interchanged so that $y$ is first, followed by $z$, and then $x$, we can effectively ignore the outermost integral with respect to $x$:  we then find that if $\sqrt{x} \le y \le 1$, then $$1-\sqrt{x} \ge 1-y \ge 0,$$ from which it follows that $$0 \le z \le 1-y \le 1 - \sqrt{x}.$$  Therefore, the integral with respect to $z$ should be $$\int_{z=0}^{1-\sqrt{x}}$$ and the integral with respect to $y$ should be $$\int_{y=\sqrt{x}}^{1-z}.$$  Putting this together, we get $$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{z=0}^{1 - \sqrt{x}} \int_{y=\sqrt{x}}^{1-z} 2y \, dy \, dz \, dx.$$

Evaluating the original integral gives $$\begin{align*} \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=\sqrt{x}}^1 \int_{z=0}^{1-y} 2y \, dz \, dy \, dx 
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=\sqrt{x}}^{1} 2y \Bigl[z\Bigr]_{z=0}^{1-y} \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=\sqrt{x}}^{1} 2y(1-y) \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \left[ y^2 - \frac{2}{3}y^3 \right]_{y=\sqrt{x}}^1 \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \left(\frac{1}{3} - x + \frac{2}{3} x^{3/2} \right) \, dx \\
&= \left[\frac{x}{3} - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{4}{15} x^{5/2} \right]_{x=0}^1 \\
&= \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{4}{15} = \frac{1}{10}.
\end{align*}$$
Evaluating the second integral gives
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{z=0}^{1 - \sqrt{x}} \int_{y=\sqrt{x}}^{1-z} 2y \, dy \, dz \, dx
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{z=0}^{1-\sqrt{x}} \Bigl[y^2\Bigr]_{y = \sqrt{x}}^{1-z} \, dz \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{z=0}^{1-\sqrt{x}} (1-z)^2 - x \, dz \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \left[z - z^2 + \frac{z^3}{3} - xz\right]_{z=0}^{1-\sqrt{x}} \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 (1-\sqrt{x})(1-x) - (1-\sqrt{x})^2 + \frac{(1-\sqrt{x})^3}{3} \, dx \\
&= \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{1}{3} - x + \frac{2}{3}x^{3/2} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{10}. \end{align*}$$